# \b boundary regex not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to use the `\b` regex to match whole words but I coudn't get it to work.

```
match = re.match(r'\bcat\b', 'the cat is sleeping')
print(match) # prints None
```

With this piece of code, I was expecting to get a match on `cat`, but it returns `None`. I tried running the code on my local machine, and also on an online python shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` starts the match from the beginning of the string. Since your `cat` is not starting the string, so that's why it's not matching.

You need to use `re.search` in this case.

```
re.search(r'\bcat\b', 'the cat is sleeping')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 7), match='cat'>
```